# Error Trying to Mock DbContext EF Core .NET 6 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Fixture

```
    public class RepositoryFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public RepositoryFixture()
        {
            var moviesMock = CreateDbSetMock(GetFakeListOfMovies());
            var mockDbContext = new Mock<UserStoryContext>();
            mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.UserStories).Returns(moviesMock.Object);
            Repository = new UserStoryRepository(>>>mockDbContext<<<); // error on this line, see mockDbContext
        }

        public UserStoryRepository Repository { get; set; }

        private IEnumerable<UserStory> GetFakeListOfMovies()
        {
            var movies = new List<UserStory>
            {
                new UserStory {UserStoryId = 1, Title = "Movie 1"},
                new UserStory {UserStoryId = 2, Title = "Movie 2"},
                new UserStory {UserStoryId = 3, Title = "Movie 3"}
            };

            return movies;
        }

        private static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateDbSetMock<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements) where T : class
        {
            var elementsAsQueryable = elements.AsQueryable();
            var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Provider);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Expression);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.ElementType);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator());

            return dbSetMock;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

DbContext

```
    public class UserStoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<UserStoryTheme> UserStoryThemes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserStoryChampion> UserStoryChampions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserStory> UserStories { get; set; }

        public UserStoryContext(DbContextOptions<UserStoryContext> options)
           : base(options)
        {
            base.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

Error
[image]

I'm using Moq to try and mock my DbContext and DbSet so I can unit test my repository.

Can someone please help me understand what's wrong and how to fix?  I've made sure to make the DbSet virtual as I've seen in other posts, but still no resolution.  Thanks!

Jason

Comment: `DbContext` is complex and very difficult to mock as a result. The EF team advises using the in-memory database provider instead.

Comment: Yep, I've seen that.  I've also seen that using the in-memory db is more like an integration test and not a unit test.  I'm learning.  Learning about software development, C#, Mocking, and unit testing to name a few.  I might actually switch to in-memory for my project but I'd still like to understand what I'm doing wrong to get this error.  Thanks.

Comment: Whether it's an integration test depends on how you use it.

Comment: Please copy the error text into the post. Screenshots should be supplemental, and only if necessary.

Comment: Well the error you posted is quite clear, you are attempting to assign Mock<T> to T. To get from Mock<T> to T, you need to use its Object property.

Comment: Regarding the overall issue, I agree with @madreflection that mocking DbContext won't get you far and the tests produced in this manner won't properly verify the logic as there is no translation to SQL (or whatever) happening. Not all LINQ queries are translatable. Using in-memory provider has the same issue and the official docs state as much. I would recommend using in-memory sqlite instead and configure it to behave like your target provider. It's a bit of work but you get things like constraints, transactions and collations.

Comment: I'm switching my project to use an in-memory store.  Now, I think I'm getting myself all confused.  If I'm testing my controller, I still need to mock my repository even if I'm using an in-memory store, right?  Or no?

Comment: _but I'd still like to understand what I'm doing wrong to get this error_ - you are trying to mock DbContext this is what you are doing wrong ;)

Comment: You need to pass mockDbContext.Object to your repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning an object of type *Mock* to the variable *mockDbContext*. The UserStoryRepository is expecting an object of type *UserStoryContext* in the constructor.

You need to change the construction of the repository to:

```
Repository = new UserStoryRepository(mockDbContext.Object);
```